# Error with Blender-OMSI-Exporter : 'Object' object is not iterable

Tags: python, export, add-on

I'm trying to export each selected object, but it tells me that objects cannot be iterated.

```
import bpy
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path
from io_export_o3d.exporter import Exporter

context = bpy.context
objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
exporter = Exporter()

for ob in objects:
    context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
    Path = pathlib.WindowsPath('D:/Users/user/Downloads/3D Object Converter/models/export/atr11\\') / (ob.name + '.o3d')
    ob.select_set(True)
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        exporter.export(ob, Path)
        ob.select_set(False)
```

This is the exporter class used:
https://github.com/Road-hog123/Blender-OMSI-Exporter

This is the error:

```
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\user\Downloads\3D Object Converter\models\2302\untitled.blend\Text", line 16, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\sor ji\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\io_export_o3d\exporter.py", line 291, in export
    mesh.triangles = [meshio.Triangle(vs, m) for vs, m in triangles()]
  File "C:\Users\sor ji\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\io_export_o3d\exporter.py", line 291, in <listcomp>
    mesh.triangles = [meshio.Triangle(vs, m) for vs, m in triangles()]
  File "C:\Users\sor ji\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\io_export_o3d\exporter.py", line 214, in triangles
    for me, slots, vertex_groups in meshes():
  File "C:\Users\sor ji\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\io_export_o3d\exporter.py", line 145, in meshes
    for obj in self.filter_objects(objects):
  File "C:\Users\sor ji\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\io_export_o3d\exporter.py", line 109, in filter_objects
    return [o for o in objects if o.type == 'MESH']
TypeError: 'Object' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `exporter.export` is expecting a `Iterable[Object]` as its first argument, not an `Object`. Either pass all your objects at once or use `[ob]` to export one.